# selecting concat with the %-Tag exculding one character

Tags: mysql, select, concatenation

I like to select all rows from the table which end with any characters after the beginning `abc`. I can do this with this `%`-Tag. Now I want to select the same, all characters after the 'abc' but not the `/` character in the `%`. How can I form this?

```
SELECT * FROM table where myColumn LIKE CONCAT( 'abc',  '%' );
```

Comment: can you give example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table where myColumn LIKE 'abc%' and myColumn not like '%/%'
```